# NSTableView hideRows leaves empty space where old rows once were

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I'm working on the ability to hide and show rows when a users taps on a button. When I call `NSTableView.hideRows` the rows do animate away as expected, but the `tableView` doesn't pull the remaining rows along with it, so a large gap is shown in the middle of the `tableView`. If I tap on an additional row, then I get the animation of the remaining rows getting pulled up.

Images shown below...

Table with all rows:

[image: Table with all rows]

Gap shown:

[image]

Code:

```
  func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return 50
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier.testCell, owner: nil) as? TestCell {
      cell.label.stringValue = String(row)
      return cell
    }
    return nil
  }

  func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let tableViewObject = notification.object as? NSTableView {
      let index = tableViewObject.selectedRow
      if index >= 0 {
        self.tableView.hideRows(at: IndexSet(arrayLiteral: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), withAnimation: .slideUp)
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there something I missed?

Git link  https://gitlab.com/RollingGoron/broken-nstable

****************Update*******************

Calling `self.tableView.noteHeightOfRows(withIndexesChanged: range)` after `hideRows` fixes the problem in my example project, but doesn't solve the problem if you try and hide rows that are off screen.

e.g. If you try and hide 100 rows, it will animate them away but instead of leaving a 100 row gap, a gap ~50 will be left depending on the size of the rows.

I would love to see if it's possible to hideRows that are currently off screen.

Comment: I don't see the same problem you see. When I hide rows in my NSOutlineView,  the outline view rows below do slideUp immediately.   I do see a bug, though... I do see that *if* a parent outline row is disclosed, and you hide the parent, then the child does not also hide itself automatically.

Things to try: call tableView.reloadData and/or tableView.setNeedsDisplay after calling hideRows ?

Comment: @KeithKnauber Is NSOutlineView a subclass of NSTableView? I'll post a link to the git repo, I'm thinking it's an NSTableView issue only.

Comment: Here is git repo where you should be able to reproduce. Tiny example project.

https://gitlab.com/RollingGoron/broken-nstable

Comment: @KeithKnauber setNeedsDisplay doesn't seem to help and reloadData resets the hidden rows, making everything appear again.

Comment: Yes NSOutlineView is a subclass of NSTableView

Comment: Whoops, caching is probably the wrong approach.  Someone else needs to provide a better answer.

Comment: @KeithKnauber I did come across something that helped. Calling self.tableView.noteHeightOfRows(withIndexesChanged: range) after .hideRows seems to have fixed the problem. But I noticed that it has limitations if you try and hide too many rows. The animation stops abruptly so instead of showing a gap of lets say, 50 rows, it shows a gap of 25, because the animation stopped drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it.

I think there IS a bug with the hideRows(at ) func in NSTableView, but you can get around this by doing the following.

1. Call tableView.hideRows(at)
2. Call tableView.noteHeightOfRows(withIndexesChanged: range)
3. Add this piece of code to your `tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?`

   ```
   if tableView.hiddenRowIndexes.contains(row) {
     return nil
   }
   ```

This will ensure the tableView doesn't attempt to draw the row when it's animating away.